# The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002) (Crystal-report)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm using visual studio 2010 C# and I have installed Crystal-report, when I'm trying to create a new crystal report, I'm getting following error message as below:

**The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)**

Can anyone please provide help to fix this problem?

Comment: Nobody will be able to help, I'm afraid until you provide a lot more context; what piece of code brings up the error? What is the name of the file it doesn't find?..

Comment: @TaW I just created a form , added CrystalReportViewer, clicked "Create a New Crystal report", named it as CrystalReport1.rpt and pressed ok, I'm getting the error message as I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was getting that error because I was using Express edition.

Answer (score -1):

[image: ScreenShot]

Right click on Reporting from Toolbox and click on choose item , then find Crystal Report.WindowsForm version 13 and checked the checkbox

Comment: Keep in mind this person solved their own problem over 2 years ago.